# JavaScript preventDefault is not a fuction

Tags: javascript

I am trying to detect a click on a button using JavaScript and prevent the default action

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Click Here</button>

function myFunction(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Function Has Run")
}
```

I am getting the error

```
event.preventDefault is not a function
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `this !== event`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an `onclick` function, the value of `this` is the *element*, not the event.

`event` is the first argument to the `onclick` function.

You could do this:

```
onclick="myFunction(event)"
```

… but I'm honestly not sure if `onclick` attributes set up a local `event` variable of if this is the [global event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

It is better to bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction)
```

Then `myFunction` *itself* will be the event handler so the first argument passed to it will be the event object, and `this` will be the element to which the event handler is bound.

Comment: Thanks, well explained!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want to access the event inside, I have figured out that passing the event directly in your `onclick` attribute works the best.

If you wish to use a different `this`, you will have to bind it using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Your code would look similar to this in the end:

```
<button onclick="myFunction.call('new this', event)">Click Here</button>

function myFunction(event) {

    console.log(this); // "new this"
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("Function Has Run")
}
```